# find daily mean of grouped count when there are multiple entries on same day

Tags: r

Fairly new at using R, and I am trying to get the per day average for the count of observations.  My data set contains individual entries for each procedure conducted.  Like the following:

```
Group   Date   
body 1  14-Aug-2021
body 1  14-Aug-2021
body 1  20-Aug-2021
body 2  15-Aug-2021
body 3  16-Aug-2021
```

The data spans 10 years, with 40,000 observations.  There are multiple groups(300+), many with multiple same day entries.  I used dplyr to get frequency by date using the following code:

Using data set=data

```r
answer <- data %>%
  group_by(Group, Date) %>%
  summarise(frequency_received = n()) %>%
  arrange(frequency_received)
```

I want the average, per day, for the grouped variable "Group.  Essentially the average of the results from the above code, by group(ie body 1- avg=1.5/day).  Uncertain about how to do this, I tried the following but got an error:

```r
answer <- data %>%
  group_by(Surgeon.Last.Name, Procedure.Date) %>%
  summarise(Mean=mean(frequency_received = n())) %>%
  arrange(frequency_received)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your second code block is inconsistent with the first (new column names), please be clear.  Also, you mention *"got an error"*: there are hundreds of errors, do not make us guess. Try `summarize(Mean = mean(frequency_received))`.

Comment: Apologies for inconsistencies, and lack or error identification.  Problem has been solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following, I think, works for the example you provided:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
    ~Group,   ~Date,
"body1",  "14-Aug-2021",
"body1",  "14-Aug-2021",
"body1",  "20-Aug-2021",
"body2",  "15-Aug-2021",
"body3",  "16-Aug-2021"
)

df %>%
    group_by(Group, Date) %>%
    count() %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    summarize(frequency_received = mean(n))
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked out as I had wanted!

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting the answer?